# Number of ways to partition $n$ distinct elements to $k$ distinct boxes where each numbers appears at most twice *in total* and boxes are not empty

Tags: combinatorics

An attempt to solve an easier question, where element appears at most once, then for each box choose one of the elements which adds up to $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} $

Then for the rest, each element can be added to a box or be left out, hence we have $(k+1)^{n-k}$ and together $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} (k+1)^{n-k}$.

How can we solve this with the extra complexity of every element can appear at most twice (and not only at most once)?

Clearer explanation of the question:

We have two elements with the number 1 (they are considered identical to each other), two elements with number 2, $\dots$,  two elements with the number $n$. ($2n$ elements in total). how many ways to divide them into $k$ boxes, where each box is not empty, and we can throw some of the elements away?

So for $n=2$ $k=2$ we have:

$(1) (1)$

$(1) (2)$

$(2) (1)$

$(2) (2)$

$(1) (1,2)$

$(1) (2,2)$

$(2) (1,2)$

$(2) (1,1)$

$(1,2)(1) $

$(2,2)(1) $

$(1,2)(2) $

$(1,1)(2) $

$(1,2) (1,2)$

$(1,1) (2,2)$

$(2,2) (1,1)$

$(1) (1,2,2)$

$(2) (1,1,2)$

$(1,2,2) (1)$

$(1,1,2) (2)$

So here the answer is $19$ where the boxes are denoted by $(*)$, they are distinct but there is no order inside the boxes.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  When you say "each number appears at most twice" are you saying that we can duplicate the numbers?  Or did you mean to say that no box can contain more than two numbers?

Comment: The first one, each element/number can appear at most twice and the boxes can contain any amount of elements/numbers but cannot be empty.

Comment: So...even though the numbers are distinct, we can duplicate them if we want to?

Comment: Yes e.g. a box can have the second element twice (but not three times) and two distict boxes can both contain the same element (but only two boxes) and we cannot have a box contain two of the same element and have the same element appear in any other box

Comment: maybe easier to explain it as have two size-n sets of elements with numbers from 1 to n, dividing them to $k$ boxes where some elements can be left out and all the boxes are not empty.

Comment: The duplicated elements can't appear in the same box?  Really, the rules are not clear at all.  Perhaps a few numerical examples would clarify things.

Comment: @oren1 do you mean that for example 12 distinct element into 4 distinct boxes with each boxes contain at least 2 elemnts etc ?

Comment: Don't leave critical information for the comments.  Your post is not clear, please edit it for clarity.  Give a clear example...as in for the case $\{1,2,3\}$ going into $3$ boxes.

Comment: @oren1 In the first glance , i think that inclusion-exclusion may be used , all distribution $k^{2n} $- (first box empty or second box empty or....k th box empty )

Comment: First of all I do not understand your answer to the easier question. If there are $n$ elements and each element can appear at most once, and there are $k$ boxes and none of them can be empty, your answer is not correct. Also in your question, it seems you are not required to pick all elements which means I could choose $k$ elements, $k+1$ elements and so on...

Comment: Thanks, Indeed I now see the easier question answer has double count, will fix this. and for the latter comment please see the example I added